# Keeping column values from nested queries (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT code_c,count(*) FROM photographs WHERE code_c IN (
    SELECT code_c FROM collections WHERE id_u IN(
        SELECT id_u FROM users WHERE activated = 1
    )
)
GROUP BY code_c
```

We have Collections, Photographs and Users. Users have Collections, and Collections have Photographs

Based on that query, I'm basically trying to know how many photographs are there in each collection for those users who are "activated". The question is, how can I keep the "id_u" column from the "users" (inner query) query to use it on the photographs query (outer query).

NOTE: Let's suppose we cannot use JOIN; I'm using Oracle.

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT code_c, max(sq.id_u), count(*) FROM photographs WHERE code_c IN (
   SELECT code_c FROM collections WHERE id_u IN(
       SELECT id_u FROM users WHERE activated = 1
   ) 
) as sq
GROUP BY code_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a bunch of nested queries.  Just use `join`s and `group by`.  If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT c.code_c, count(*) as num_photos,
       sum(case when u.activated = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_activated
FROM collections c JOIN
     users u
     ON c.id_u = u.id_u JOIN
     photographs p
     ON p.code_c = c.code_c
GROUP BY c.code_c
```